# Regexreplace function to turn multiple " \n " into a single one

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How to replace consecutive newlines by one single newline in Google Sheets using regexrepleace function (or any other function).

Input: `A Novus typ 4/26 C keskeny tűzőgépkapcsok alkalmasak: \n  \n  profil fa \n   panelek \n   drótháló \n   farostlemez rögzítéséhez \n   \n \n   \n    \n   \n`

Output: `A Novus typ 4/26 C keskeny tűzőgépkapcsok alkalmasak: \n profil fa \n panelek \n drótháló \n farostlemez rögzítéséhez \n`

Comment: are those real \n or just a placeholder for new line?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Thank your for your time. This is a spreadsheet with a few real life examples: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11zPxQWGB5PSVVFbdwFGAXuawZNY0FhzBCmclJODesd8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try brute force:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A:A, CHAR(10), )), 
 "\\n \\n \\n \\n \\n \\n|\\n \\n \\n \\n \\n|\\n \\n \\n \\n|\\n \\n \\n|\\n \\n|\\n", "\\n")))
```

[image: 0]